# Unable to subscribe a rxjs response during a get by id call

Tags: rest, angular, rxjs, subscribe

I'm following the [angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) tutorial and I'm trying to call my real REST api without simulating the web API.
When I try to get a single Tune by id I'm unable to subscribe the object and then show it in the view. Below the code:

hero.service excerpt:

```
  getTune(id: string): Promise<TuneDetail> {
    const url = `${this.tunesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TuneDetail)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

tune-detail.ts

```
 export class TuneDetail {
  _id: string;
  tuneTitle: string;
  tuneAuthorName: string;
  grilleAuthorName: string;
  comments: string;
  timestamp: string;
  votes: number;
  grille_intro:string[];
  grille_outro:string[];
  grille:string[];
  userId: string;
  avatarSvg:string;;
}
```

tune-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TuneDetail } from '../tune_detail';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tune-detail',
  templateUrl: './tune-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tune-detail.component.css']
})
export class TuneDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  tune: TuneDetail;
  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getTune(params['id']))
    .subscribe(t => this.tune = t); //At debug time I can see t object filled with all data.
  }


  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

tune-detail.component.html

```
<button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
<div *ngIf="tune">
 <h2>{{tune.tuneTitle}} details!</h2>
 <div><label>id: </label>{{tune.grilleAuthorName}}</div>
 <div>
   <label>name: </label>
   <input [(ngModel)]="tune.tuneTitle" placeholder="name"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I try to debug the tune-detail.component.ts I can see t object is correctly filled with server data item but I'm unable to show this.tune in the tune-detail.component.html

What is wrong?

UPDATE: The is correct!

I found the problem is server side in json response

this is the response whe I try to get by id

```
[{"_id":"5894f196f307de607c000018","avatarSvg":"images/svg/violin.svg","votes":1,"tuneAuthorName":"Turner Layton","tuneTitle":"After you've gone","grilleAuthorName":"test","userId":"320004","__v":1,"grille":[[{"cellValue":"C6","cellId":"00"},{"cellValue":"%","cellId":"01"},{"cellValue":"C-6","cellId":"02"},{"cellValue":"G13/Ab","cellId":"47"}]],"grille_outro":[],"grille_intro":[],"timestamp":"2017-02-03T21:10:17.281Z"}]
```

the problem is due to the external brackets. I changed the REST get API in order to respond without [] and now It works like a charm!

Comment: Why are you mixing observables and promises? Stick with observables and your code will be a lot simpler.

Comment: You have a conflict between `@Input() tune` and `this.tune = t`. Both pieces of code are trying to set same `tune` property. It's either one or the other.

Comment: AngularFrance, I found the problem. It was server side. The json was an array even when I try to get by Id. So I can solve change this.tune = t[0] or server side.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you need to use the `async` pipe as you are populating `tune` asynchronously thorough an observable.

Else, try to output tune in your HTML by writing the following:
Tune: {{tune | json}} 
It should pretty print the JSON value

Comment: No need for the  `async` pipe since his code is explicitly subscribing to the observable. It's either "no `subscribe()` + `async` pipe" OR "`subscribe()` + no `async` pipe", but not both.